# Module has no Export Member

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Error

app.module.ts

```
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk';
```

> Error:  Module "d:/projectname/nodule_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk has no experted Member CdkTableModule.

When i try import

```
  import {MatCoreModule} from '@angular/material';
```

> Error:  Module "d:/projectname/nodule_modules/@angular/matrial/material has no experted Member MatCoreModule.

ng version

```
            Angular CLI: 1.6.7
            Node: 8.3.0
            OS: win32 x64
            Angular: 4.4.6
            ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
            ... http, language-service, platform-browser
            ... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

            @angular/animation: 4.0.0-beta.8
            @angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
            @angular/cli: 1.6.7
            @angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
            @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
            @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
            @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
            @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
            @ngtools/webpack: 1.9.7
            @schematics/angular: 0.1.17
            typescript: 2.7.1
            webpack: 3.10.0
```

package.json

```
                                        {
                                "name": "angular2-bug-testing",
                                "version": "0.0.0",
                                "license": "MIT",
                                "scripts": {
                                "ng": "ng",
                                "start": "ng serve",
                                "build": "ng build",
                                "test": "ng test",
                                "lint": "ng lint",
                                "e2e": "ng e2e"
                                },
                                "private": true,
                                "dependencies": {
                                "@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
                                "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
                                "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
                                "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
                                "angular-datatables": "^4.4.1",
                                "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
                                "core-js": "^2.5.3",
                                "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
                                "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.5.1",
                                "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
                                "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
                                "jquery": "^3.3.1",
                                "json-server": "^0.12.1",
                                "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
                                "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
                                },
                                "devDependencies": {
                                "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
                                "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
                                "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.6",
                                "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.8",
                                "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
                                "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
                                "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
                                "@types/node": "^6.0.96",
                                "codelyzer": "^3.2.2",
                                "jasmine-core": "^2.9.1",
                                "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
                                "karma": "^1.7.1",
                                "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
                                "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
                                "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.1",
                                "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
                                "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
                                "protractor": "^5.3.0",
                                "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
                                "tslint": "^5.9.1",
                                "typescript": "^2.7.1"
                                }
                                }
```

- can anyone suggest what im missing new  2.0.0-beta.12.
- Earlier i try to import

  ```
   import {MdCoreModule} from '@angular/material';
  ```

Comment: but i cannot understand import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material'; visual studio is not showing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import has wrong import path. Should be this:

```
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
```

Second is removed:

> MdCoreModule has been removed. Most of its functionality has been
>   moved to @angular/cdk over the last few releases.

[gitHub](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/b2ad30b3f587e6cd5be944622202bbf23a78375b/CHANGELOG.md#L1325)

Comment: Thanks Jd for Help can you pleas tell how to fix issue if the path change issue found in new release.

Comment: @afeef - Open gitHub and search in their repo. They always pronounce all changes and changes are also visible in the source code - you can see yourself where some particular module is located.

Comment: jd im having problem while using mat-slide-toggle  problem is slide toglle is not visible .<mat-slide-toggle
    [checked]="stateCtrl.disabled"
    (change)="stateCtrl.disabled ? stateCtrl.enable() : stateCtrl.disable()">
    Disable Input?
  </mat-slide-toggle> though i have used hammer js cdn path in index.html . can you please help

Comment: hi Jd Thanks for  reminding now i have accepted your answer thanks .cheers!.

Comment: Thanks JD I Have asked new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684147/angular-mat-slide-toggle-is-not-visible please have a look