# Angular Material Slide Toggle Not displaying

Tags: angular, angular-material, slider

I'm trying to use mat-slide-toggle in my site, but the component remains invisible without an actual error. Other Angular Materials components such as tooltips and dialogs work fine.

I have already tried adding import 'hammerjs' to my main.ts file and imported deeppurple-amber to my style.css, along with importing the correct modules to my app.module.ts file (attached), as written here: [angular - mat-slide-toggle is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684147/angular-mat-slide-toggle-is-not-visible) .

app.module.ts:

```
    imports: [FormsModule,BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatSlideToggleModule, ]
    exports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, MatSlideToggleModule],
    providers: [ MatSlideToggleModule,  ],
```

style.css:

```
    @import './indigo-pink.css';
    @import './deeppurple-amber.css';
```

html:

```
    <mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

ts:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { ManageAdditionsComponent_Logic } from "./ManageAdditions.component"
    import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
    import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

Comment: Any luck with it? I have the same problem...

Comment: @Matzy I did eventually figure it out but I can't remember the trick that did it, possibly importing both MatSlideToggleModule and MatSlideToggle.
`import { MatSlideToggleModule, MatSlideToggle } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';


exports: [MatSlideToggleModule]
`